# WIX Installer getting Bad condition and sequence error

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I want my custom action to be executed after the complete installation is been done. Went through so many sites but didn't get it work.

```
<Binary Id="DepTypeCustomActionBinary" SourceFile="$(var.SolutionDir)\Proj.Setup\DepCustomAction.CA.dll"/>

<CustomAction Id="CheckDepType" BinaryKey="DepTypeCustomActionBinary" DllEntry="CustomAction1" Impersonate="no" Execute="deferred" Return="check" HideTarget="no" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>      
      <Custom Action="CheckDepType" After="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Above is my code and I am getting below error:

`CheckDepType is a in-script custom action.  It must be sequenced in between the InstallInitialize action and the InstallFinalize action in the InstallExecuteSequence table`

Comment: What is this custom action doing / checking? Did you read up on [Commit Custom Actions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367991(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: I did tried Commit with after="InstallFiles" but didn't work. My CustomAction check for dlls and then remove it.

Comment: What is the custom action doing? We have to ask in order to understand what solutions could work for you. [Commit custom actions have many drawbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19636158/129130). Are you changing something? Are you inspecting something? Are you cleaning up something?

Comment: My custom Action check if the install folder is Program Files then it deletes few dlls like dscrt40.dll.

Comment: Well the error is obviously caused because you scheduled a deferred action outside of the elevated execution sequence which, as stated in the error, is between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize. You cannot schedule a deferred action after InstallFinalize.

Comment: Added some more detail to my answer below. Please provide us some more details on why you need to delete this file, whether you are installing it as part of your setup, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I'll just add a short answer rather than adding too many comments. I am not sure what `dscrt40.dll` is doing - is it a file you use during installation for some runtime dependency? I wouldn't recommend installing your own files into a pre-existing folder - if that is what you are doing.

I suppose you could try to use the [**RemoveFile construct**](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/removefile.html) to have the Windows Installer engine remove the file in question on install, this should prevent the need for a custom action. You must not do this if you install the file you are removing via a Windows Installer component first - then self-repair is likely to kick in to put it back afterwards.

A custom action that makes changes to the system can not be sequenced after `InstallFinalize` - the database change transaction ends with `InstallFinalize`, and you no longer have elevation for the custom actions that follow after `InstallFinalize` (immediate mode custom actions can be inserted, but they will fail unless you are running with admin rights - don't try it - it is impossible to rely on). You can only insert change custom actions (deferred custom actions) after `InstallInitialize` and before `InstallFinalize` in the `InstallExecuteSequence`.

You should be aware that files will be present on disk after the action `InstallFiles` has run (technically on the second run through the InstallExecuteSequence - the first run - immediate - just creates an execution script, the second run - deferred - executes the script), so you can in principle delete files after this action has run, but it doesn't really make sense to do so.

- Why do you need to delete this file?
- Do you install this file yourself or is it a pre-existing file?

Comment: My application is 32bit application so it always gets installed in Program File(x86). But if it gets installed in Program Files folder it fails due to some dlls. So my custom checks if the installed folder is Program Files then delete those dlls. That's the reason I want to do it after installation. dscrt40.dll is for image processing. Secondly, I am totally new to Wix and  My job is to fix this issue. I went through many sites and ended up with this problem.

Comment: I was not knowing about RemoveFile construct. But seems like it will solve my problem if I can execute it with a condition. Sorry if I am posting for silly questions and thank you so much.