# What Should the Sequence Position be for a Custom Action Type 18 for Uninstalls?

Tags: windows-installer, uninstallation, custom-action

Where in the [InstallExecuteSequence table sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372038%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should a **Custom Action Type 18** (execute an app that is part of the installation) be placed so that it only runs during the uninstall because the `"REMOVE="ALL"` or an `"Installed"` condition has been applied to it - so it doesn't get deleted before running?

Comment: Just checking in to hear if you have resolved the issue? I also want to add that [the condition REMOVE="ALL" causes the custom action to run also on major upgrade uninstalls as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50917907/129130).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### WiX Mock-Up

**What tool do you use?** Here is a quick **WiX snippet**:

**`Synchronous`, `deferred execution in system context`, `ignore exit code`**, **`run on all types of uninstalls`** (also major upgrade uninstalls) and **`running before the RemoveFiles Action`**:

```xml
<CustomAction Id="RunExeUninstall" FileKey="notepad.exe" ExeCommand="" 
              Return="ignore" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" />

<...>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
   <Custom Action="RunExeUninstall" Before="RemoveFiles">REMOVE="ALL"</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

---

***Orca***: The above should yield something like this in the [`CustomAction table`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368062(v=vs.85).aspx) when viewed with `Orca`:

> | `Action`: RunExeUninstall | `Type`: 3154 | `Source`: Filename.exe | `Target`: |

---

### Some CA Details

Generally before the standard action **`RemoveFiles`** and **`running synchronously`** - so that **`the EXE custom action thread`** needs to complete before **`the setup's main thread`** can continue (or the main tread will likely uninstall the files before you are done in your EXE CA).

I normally set **`error processing`** to **`ignore exit code`** for uninstall custom actions (or rollback could kick in unexpectedly - putting your install back on the box by undoing the uninstall - making the setup un-uninstallable and possibly un-upgradable as well - minor upgrades should still work, but major upgrades can fail).

Does this custom action make changes to the system? (as opposed to just checking or logging something). Then it should have a corresponding **`rollback custom action`**, inserted prior in the sequence to your main custom action, undoing its changes if the setup is aborted manually (when you ignore exit code, the CA itself should not trigger rollback, but the setup can still be cancelled manually by the user, or by other CAs that check exit code - or some runtime failure not related to your custom actions - out of disk space, disc errors, etc...).

If you make **`changes to per-machine locations`** (unwriteable for standard users) you need to run with **`elevated rights`** (*`deferred execution in system context`*).

There are many pitfalls here. Note that rollback can be disabled by policy or property - causing rollback and commit custom actions to never run. I'll add some links at the bottom.

---

***Some Links*** (very good):

- [**Installation Phases and In-Script Execution Options for Custom Actions in Windows Installer**](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/isnews/200108/) (MSI-Expert Stefan Krüger of [installsite.org](http://installsite.org))
- [Windows Installer custom actions: commit action won't get executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19631519/windows-installer-custom-actions-commit-action-wont-get-executed/19636158#19636158)
- [Testing your deferred and rollback custom actions](https://www.joyofsetup.com/2008/06/18/testing-your-deferred-and-rollback-custom-actions/)

Comment: This is my first extended installation project. I am using ORCA. It looks like I may have to manually modify the MSI file with VS given your suggestions.

This executable is resetting the registry.

Comment: Using Orca isn't ideal for setup creation. It is more of a viewer than an editor, although it is excellent for what it is (one of the few tools that don't add junk when saving MSI files). Have you considered [**WiX or some of the other deployment tools**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49632260/129130) that are available?

Comment: Please see the updated text above for Orca table row in the `CustomAction table`. You also need a row in the `InstallExecuteSequence table`, but I think you have that already.

Comment: So you right click the MSI, select `Uninstall` and the uninstall does not complete and goes into rollback?

Comment: There are a few ways to get rid of such installations, but before overdoing things, let's try the [**Microsoft FixIt tool for installer problems**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed). Try to run it, and see if this solves your problem. If it does, then that is great. If it does not, please add a new question asking how to get rid of such installations and I will write up a couple of hacky ways that should work - but that are not recommended.

Comment: What I ended up doing, was deleting the MSI file in C:\Windows\Installer, running a repair installation and then performed a uninstall which worked.

Comment: Using the custom action type 3154 worked and sequencing before any of the removes at 3050 worked. The setup project is working!!! Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172817/discussion-between-stein-asmul-and-marc-george).

Comment: I added some follow-up comments in chat that you should be aware of. You now probably have a dangling reference to a missing MSI in C:\Windows\Installer. I would recommend you run the Microsoft FixIt tool to correct the erronous reference.

Comment: I will keep your warning about deleting those MSI's in mind. I just tested the installation in a Win10 VM as a regular user. If I run the setup directly I am posed with a permissions dialog, I provide administrator credentials and the installation fails with a System.Security.SecurityException error 1026 when running my custom action. Locally, on my development machine, NP. If I run the setup as the administrator, NP. Same locally. Ideas?

Comment: Sounds like some sort of .NET security issue - this is a .NET executable? Managed code have many challenges and pitfalls when used with MSI - I am very skeptical towards them for large scale releases. Perhaps try googling `System.Security.SecurityException error 1026` - I saw some pages with information on CAS issues (security policy).

Comment: Thinking about the issue, I would assume that if running the setup as the administrator, all of the activities are under the security context of that administrator account. When setup asks for permission, the activities are under the security context of the initializing user's account. Is there a way to tell setup to assume the security context of the authorizing user?

Comment: I remember a few minutes ago modifying the permissions on the registry key to include my basic user account, hence why I was able to run the setup on my development machine without the problem. Removing the permissions and I have the same problem locally. I guess I will just need to specify to the installers that they have to run the setup as an administrator.

Comment: There are policies involved when enabling standard users elevated rights during installation. They are set up in Active Directory. To "simulate" elevated rights, you can use the [AlwaysInstallElevated policy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367561(v=vs.85).aspx) for testing purposes on your virtual machine or test machine. **Do not use this on all your boxes!** Testing only. I should have mentioned this policy before - today most people seem to elevate to real admin rights (which are different from elevated rights).